# assign string value to img source wpf

Tags: wpf, wcf-binding, .net-4.5

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    // TODO: Assign a bindable collection of items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]

    if (Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter) >= 0)
    {
        BindData();
        BindData();
        txt1.Text = data[Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter)].Name;
        Img.Source = data[Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter)].ImagePath;
    }
```

i want to set img source as string .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836032/setting-image-source-programatically-in-metro-app-image-doesnt-appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

```
Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(data[Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter)].ImagePath));
```

---

UPDATE

In case `ImagePath` is a relative path you may write it this way:

```
var path = data[Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter)].ImagePath;
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
Img.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Does your `data[Convert.ToInt32(navigationParameter)].ImagePath` specify a valid file path? Is it an absolute or relative path?

Comment: its relative path it changes according to naviagtion

Comment: public void BindData()
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data.Add(new MyDataCollection
                {
                    Name = "This is the small Description for image " + (i + 1) + "\n\n\n\nI'm trying to use the navigation command framework in WPF to navigate \n\n ... any binding errors in the Output window, but my navigation button is disabled. ... I just want to know how I can get the Button to provide the same ability",
                    ImagePath = "Assets/Images/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg"
                });
            }

  }

Comment: Could you please edit your question? This is heard to read as comment.

Comment: public void BindData()                                                  {                                                                          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                   {                                                              data.Add(new MyDataCollection                                        { Name = "discrption " + (i + 1) +                                                                    ImagePath = "Assets/Images/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg" });                                                                           i want set imagepath as source

Comment: : The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details.

Comment: still i cant do that , the uri written with the path ,the path is correct still the expection continues

Comment: Is it a WPF or Window Runtime application?

Comment: Then it's not WPF. Apparently you need to specify absolute paths for your images.

Comment: so how can i provide with relative image , i taught wpf and win rt has same functionality

Comment: i got it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836032/setting-image-source-programatically-in-metro-app-image-doesnt-appear

Answer (score 0):

```
myImage.Source = ImageFromRelativePath(this, "relative_path_to_file_make_sure_build_set_to_content");

public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.UriSource = uri;
    return result;
}
```